# RDLC Report in Visual Studio 2012-Object Entity

Tags: entity-framework, rdlc

How to Show child property value in RDLC Report?
for Example:

```
public class Person
{
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address 
{
  public string streetName {get;set;}
}
```

How to display streetName value in RDLC Report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For All Properties we have to set [Serializable()] in Class

```
[Serializable()]
public class Person
{
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}
[Serializable()]
public class Address 
{
  public string streetName {get;set;}
  public SubAddress SubAddress{get;set;}
}

[Serializable()]
public class SubAddress
{
  public string DoorNo {get;set;}
}
```

In Report in the code tab of report Properties follwing code is used

```
 Public Function GetName(ByRef obj As Object) As String 
     If obj Is Nothing Then Return "na" 
     Else : Return obj.streetName 
     End If 
 End Function
```

and report field get it as =Code.GetName(Fields!Address.Value)

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [this blog's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2010/10/27/nested-objects-in-local-mode.aspx) from Brian Hartman, there was a change since VS2010 for the nested class in a LocalReport.

He suggest to add the attribute [Serializable()] (if applicable).

Your class will be look like this:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Person
{
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}
[Serializable()]
public class Address 
{
  public string streetName {get;set;}
}
```

Edit: added the code after some comments. Try to implement your class like this:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Person
{
    private Address _address;
    public Address Address
    {
        get
        {
            if(_address == null)
                return new Address(string.Empty);
            return _address;
        }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
        }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class Address
    {
        private string _streetName;
        public string streetName 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _streetName;
            }
            set
            {
                _streetName = value;
            }
        }
        public Address(string streetName)
        {
            _streetName = streetName;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way it will always return a value and never null.

Comment: I have added the '[Serializable()]' in my code .It worked for non nullable entity field but for nullable entity fields it is not working for eg: In Report i have checked null value for entity as **IIF(Fields!Address.Value Is Nothing," ",Fields!Address.Value.streetName )** it returns **'#error'**. _i am using Visual studio 2012_

Comment: it always returns '#error' or only if the `Fields!Address.Value` is null?

Comment: following Code used to get street name in the code tab of report property `Public Function GetName(ByRef obj As Object) As String
    If obj Is Nothing Then
        Return "na"
    Else : Return obj.streetName 
    End If
End Function`  and report field get it as `=Code.GetName(Fields!Address.Value)` .it returns na for null field and for value again it return #error

Comment: hi nanny, it is working. _one doubt is all the nested properties is to be set **[Serializable()]** in the Class_

Comment: as you can [read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) if you apply `[Serializable()]` at the top of your class, all the properties will be 'serializable'. If you don't need one or more properties, you can apply the attribute `[NonSerialized()]` to them